# Color palette not starting with CorelDraw X3

Tags: colors, coreldraw

The default color palette is not staring with my CorelDraw X3. I can add it during the execution of Corel. However, when I start this app, the color palette is not visible. So, I need to add the palette every time I use Corel. I created a keyboard shortcut to make it visible, but I would like a better solution.

How can I restore the default color palette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to press and hold <kbd>F8</kbd> while launching the program?
It restores default settings.